# MSBuild error - Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I have a visual studio solution containing some class library projects and a windows service project.

I am trying to build it using the following msbuild command:

```
MSBuild SolutionName.sln /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;OutputType=Winexe /clp:ErrorsOnly
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method
>   suitable for an entry point [C:..\BusinessObjects.csproj]

Somehow it tries to find an entry point inside a class library project instead of using the windows service project.

I believe if I try to build WindowsService.csproj instead of .sln file then it may fix the issue. However, WindowsService.CsProj does not contain all other dll references so I have to build .sln file.

Is there any other way I can fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe if I try to build WindowsService.csproj instead of .sln file
>   then it may fix the issue. However, WindowsService.CsProj does not
>   contain all other dll references so I have to build .sln file.
>
> Is there any other way I can fix this error?

Since your just build the whole solution with msbuild command line , it **means** that the parameters from your command line apply to all projects in the solution.

**As your description**, you have some class library projects in your solution which does not contains a static `Main` method, So it cannot be specified as a **Windows application**.

Projects in VS have three output types: `Console Application` and `Windows Application` contains a static `Main` function while `Class Library Application` does not contain it.

**Conclusion**

If you build a whole solution with the command line, you should make sure that all the parameters from the command line apply to all projects.

When you build a single project `Windows Service project`, just make sure the current project has a static `main` function and it actually has.

**Solution**

**1)** Since your solution contains only one `winexe` project and other class library projects, please delete `OutputType=Winexe` in the command line.

```
MSBuild SolutionName.sln /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Makes sense. I compiled .sln file (without OutputType)  followed by csproj file (with OutputType) to fix this issue.